# Is that possible to create facebook search link in iframe?

Tags: facebook, iframe

I want to search on facebook with a [lightbox plugin](http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/lightview), which uses iframe for links.
The facebook original search url is this:
https://www.facebook.com/search/results/?q=someword

But unfortunately this url comes back with this message in the console:

> Refused to display
>   'facebook.com/search/results/?q=someword' in a
>   frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Is there anyway to create a facebook search link in iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to use facebook.com like that, you must use the Graph API for those things. Luckily, there is a Search API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search

Example: `http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=somequerystring&type=user`

...of course you need to use an Access Token for that. Information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

The Public Post Search API is deprecated though, you can´t search for posts anymore. All options of the Search API are explained in the docs.

In other words: There is no API for the Graph Search.

Comment: no, you can´t use the api in an iframe like that. you need to start reading the basic docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs - forget about that weird iframe solution, it will not work. you can´t just use a specific url and be done with it.

Comment: Okey thank you
I think this is harder question like i thinked before.

Comment: that´s for sure. you need to learn about user athorization/login, access tokens and the graph api.